# How to save file from richtextbox in utf-8 or unicode in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, unicode, utf-8, richtextbox

I want to save text in some encoding type.. I want to do it without StreamWriter class. I looked for richtextbox but I couldnt see how to do it. Is there any way to save text in utf-8 or unicode from richbox ?

Answer (score 0):

utf-8 or unicode characters directly save in files or database if database field or other resource allow utf-8 or unicode characters.

Comment: thanx for comment, that means I cant choos this type? For example,I want to save a file as utf-8. I can determinate it with StreamWriter but I dont want to use it

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just put the following code and the richtextbox will create it in UTF-8 Format, but will not open, just save. But it will open perfectly in notepad! Paste this code, it will save in that directory but without showing a dialog.

```
Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(RICHTEXTBOX1.Text)
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
    fs.Close()
```